# cache_sweeper method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, tomcat6, jrubyonrails

I'm deploying my Rails 3 application to a Tomcat 6 server. I've been using `warble` to package my project up into a `war` file and so far have not had any troubles, until now. I just added a `cache_sweeper` to my application. When I tried hitting the application, I received the standard 500 error page.

Looking at my logs, I saw this:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: undefined method `cache_sweeper' for ApplicationController:Class
```

It can't find the `cache_sweeper` method? Isn't that part of Rails?

This doesn't happen while in development mode, though in development I'm using MRI ruby and using the rails server instead.

Anyone have any ideas?!

Full error:

```
SEVERE: Application Error
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: undefined method `cache_sweeper' for ApplicationController:Class
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:239:in `require'
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
    from C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
     ... 39 levels...
    from file:/C:/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/rails3app/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from <script>:2:in `new'
    from <script>:2

    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:184)
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:59)
    at org.jruby.rack.PoolingRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(PoolingRackApplicationFactory.java:94)
    at org.jruby.rack.servlet.DefaultServletDispatcher.process(DefaultServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, you have to include the module when using jruby/warble. However, this step is not necessary when using MRI and the rails server.

I added this to my `ApplicationController` and it worked:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Caching::Sweeping if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
  ...
end
```